# Comparing 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table where I have all id's and a second table where I have the id's where there was an error in the process. I need my query to select the last 3 id's before the error happened. 
For example:

```
first table:
id     |   info
___________________
100    |     1.0             
101    |     2.0                      
102    |     6.0             
103    |     9.0         
104    |     15.0         
105    |     8.0       
106    |     6.0
107    |     8.0       
108    |     6.0
109    |     8.0       
110    |     6.0



id of errors:

id        
____                                                              
104                 
110
```

So this query would have to return the values for id's:
 109,108,107,103,102 and 101

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: "last" is defined by `id`? Remember that tables don't have a concept of record order. You need to base the order off of the data.

Comment: I tried doing a left join with the top 3 id's of the first table on firsttable.id < secondtable.id, but it brings the first 3 id's of the whole table

Comment: yes they all have individual id's that were assigned to them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT result.*
FROM errors e
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 3 * 
    FROM [first table] ft 
    WHERE ft.id < e.id 
    ORDER BY ft.id DESC
) result
```

Comment: In my oipinion it is incorrect when you have gap between errors lower or equal than 3: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=a98af4afc07e071db3b0c0b868dab4d1

Answer (score 1):

This could work for you:

Setup:

```
Create Table #Errs
(
Id Int
);

Insert Into #Errs Values
(104), (110)

Create Table #tbl
(
Id Int,
Info Decimal(6,2)
);

Insert Into #tbl Values
(100,1.0),
(101,2.0),
(102,6.0),
(103,9.0),
(104,15.0),
(105,8.0),
(106,6.0),
(107,8.0),
(108,6.0),
(109,8.0),
(110,6.0)
```

Query

```
With cte As
(
   Select 
      Id,
      LAG(Id,1,Null) OVER(Order By Id) As iderror1,
      LAG(Id,2,Null) OVER(Order By Id) As iderror2,
      LAG(Id,3,Null) OVER(Order By Id) As iderror3 
   From #tbl t
) 
Select iderror1 As ErrorList From cte Where Id In (Select Id From #Errs)
Union ALL
Select iderror2 As ErrorList From cte Where Id In (Select Id From #Errs)
Union ALL
Select iderror3 As ErrorList From cte Where Id In (Select Id From #Errs)
Order By ErrorList
```

If your IDs are not in sequential order, you can use (Select NULL) as Below:

```
With cte As
(
   Select 
      Id,
      LAG(Id,1,Null) OVER(Order By (Select NULL)) As iderror1,
      LAG(Id,2,Null) OVER(Order By (Select NULL)) As iderror2,
      LAG(Id,3,Null) OVER(Order By (Select NULL)) As iderror3 
   From #tbl t
) 
Select iderror1 As ErrorList From cte Where Id In (Select Id From #Errs)
Union ALL
Select iderror2 As ErrorList From cte Where Id In (Select Id From #Errs)
Union ALL
Select iderror3 As ErrorList From cte Where Id In (Select Id From #Errs)
Order By ErrorList
```

Results

```
ErrorList
--------
101
102
103
107
108
109
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use windowed function to calculate helper group `SUM()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` to get 3 last rows:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT t1.*, -sub.c+ SUM(sub.c) OVER(ORDER BY t1.id) AS grp
  FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) sub(c)
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY id DESC) rn
  FROM cte
)
SELECT id, info
FROM cte2
WHERE rn BETWEEN 2 AND 4
ORDER BY id;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=f5ae7da47b4407b1a6999fe886a701d7)**